TiMidity++ Daemon doesn't work with sudo
This is the output from Bash command-line, detailed case by case:
netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ /usr/bin/timidity -iA # -OO is default without sudo
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3


netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ /usr/bin/timidity -iA -OO # Without sudo it works in any case
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3


netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ /usr/bin/timidity -iA -Os # Without sudo it works in any case
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 32768, period size 8192 bytes
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3


netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ sudo /usr/bin/timidity -iA # -Os is default with sudo
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 33868, period size 3760 bytes
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3


netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ sudo /usr/bin/timidity -iA -Os # No audio playing
Requested buffer size 32768, fragment size 8192
ALSA pcm 'default' set buffer size 33868, period size 3760 bytes
TiMidity starting in ALSA server mode
Opening sequencer port: 128:0 128:1 128:2 128:3

If audio is played while the above command is running, no sound will be heard.
netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ sudo /usr/bin/timidity -iA -Os # Audio playing
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1032:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Can't open pcm device 'default'.
Couldn't open ALSA pcm device (`s')


netcom@netcom-Vostro-15-3510:~$ sudo /usr/bin/timidity -iA -OO # With sudo it doesn't work in any case
(null): Input/output error
Couldn't open Libao mode (`O')

TiMidity++ Daemon doesn't work with sudo, neither when using -OO nor when using -Os.
Why?

Why do you want to use sudo? I don't know much about this, but I'm guessing your user owns the audio processes in your session, so why would you want to try to connect as root?

Because I want to run timidity as a service on startup, which must be a multi-user service.

Please [edit] the question and describe the entire scenario. It sounds like it would make more sense to start this for every user and not as a system thing.
